# Ruby's Exception Error classes

Tags: ruby

You can create a subclass of an exception to make it more descriptive, but how should you set the default 'message'?

```
class MyError < StandardError
  # default message = "You've triggered a MyError"
end

begin
  raise MyError, "A custom message"
rescue Exception => e
  p e.message
end

begin
  raise MyError
raise Exception => e
  p e.message
end
```

The first should output 'A custom message'

The second should output 'You've triggered a MyError'

Any suggestions as to best practice?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Define an initialize method, which takes the message as an argument with a default value. Then call `StandardError`'s initialize method with that message (using `super`).

```
class MyError < StandardError
  def initialize(msg = "You've triggered a MyError")
    super(msg)
  end
end
```

Comment: Just `super` is enough. If you call `super` without an argument list, it will simply pass on all arguments, which is why, when you actually want to pass *no* arguments, you must explicitly call `super()`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Why all the custom error classes inherit from `StandardError` ? Any reason behind it?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Because its safe. Whenever rescuing from errors it should be a `StandardError` (or lower), as higher level errors such as `Exception` can even be thrown when hitting CTL-C etc. See this for more info http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2012/11/01/don-t-rescue-exception-rescue-standarderror

Answer (score 3):

You may also overwrite the `message` method in your subclass and return the string you'd like displayed. I prefer this as it seems to keep things a little cleaner if you want to do anything interesting before displaying the message.

```
class CustomError < StandardError

  def initialize(error_code, error_info)
    @code, @info = error_code, error_info
  end

  def message
    "<Code: #{@code}> <Info: #{@info}>"
  end

end
```